# codeigniter assets handling trouble

Tags: codeigniter

i am having trouble about to link my css and js files on code igniter. i am new on codeigniter and need some help. i look for it but couldnt find a really working solution. my folder structure is like:

```
-> system
-> application
-> js
  -> jquery.js
-> css
  -> style.css
-> images
-> .htaccess
-> index.php
```

my base url is like http://subdomain.mydomain.com/ working on a sub domain

here is my .htaccess file for pass out /index.php/controller i m giving this because i dont know if it effect the issue.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|stylesheets|scripts|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

and here is my header.php - i use a simple template structure, header content footer loading

```
   <?php 
    $css = array(
          'href' => 'css/style.css',
          'rel' => 'stylesheet',
          'type' => 'text/css',
          'media' => 'screen'
        );
        echo link_tag($css);

    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" />
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

here i tried html helper for css and also i tried base_url()/css but didnt work both. and also for jquery lib didnt work. it returns on page source like

```
src="http://subdomain.mydomain.com/js/jquery.js"
```

when i click it, it must show the codes which inside of my file but it shows 404 not found. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line and try once:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|stylesheets|scripts|robots\.txt)
```

OR Use this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```